# create-react-app and large Heruko Slug Size?

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I am developing a Front-end Application and hosting via Heruko

The Problem is that the slug size is too large when i investigated the issue I find out there is files like

```
/node_modules
/build
/src
/public
package.json
package-lock.json
tsconfig.json
README.md
```

[image]

The Official document says to use `.slugignore` file
but the problem is that i need to use `src` and other files in build process
I have found a solution for that but using this [heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/lostmyname/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean)

when i tried it i am able to remove

```
/src
/public
package.json
package-lock.json
tsconfig.json
README.md
```

> if i remove the `/node_modules` the Application Just Crash

[image]

my scripts inside `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
  "heroku-prebuild": "npm install -g serve",
  "devstart": "react-scripts start",
  "start": "serve -s build",
  "build": "react-scripts build"
},
```

now the file size is 465MB

[image]

can anyone knows how to safely remove `/node_modules` or how to better Do it.

the `/node_modules` size is larger than 410MB

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your app is purely static (html/js only in the public folder and doesn't rely on node.js as a server) you only need the public folder. It appears as though your app doesn't fit that description.

Comment: it is not static i need build folder that is generated on heruko while removing all the others
but the application just crashed

Comment: Then you need node_modules.

Comment: @KevinB I fiqure it out i need `package.json` file not `/node_modules` files

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am able to solve it using

> [heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/lostmyname/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean)

and using `.slug-post-clean` file

```
src
public
README.md
node_modules
```

I need `package.json` file only on heruko with `build` folder

Now the slug size is 57.9 MB that is 400 MB less

[image: Heruko Slug Size]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your solution! That really helped me to reduce slug size of my scala-react-app.