# How to reduce rails slug size on a react/rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, heroku, react-on-rails

I have a project with a ruby buildpack and a react buildpack the total slug size is about 109.8mb, the react side comes out to about 900kb (largest gzipped file 300kb), so I take this to mean that ruby side is taking up 108.9mb on the total slug size, is there some way to reduce this? is this normal? I havent been able to find any concrete answers while searching. please link any relevant documentation.

I dont have any assets in the file structure, the ruby side contains only models and controllers.
I have removed all possible gems from the gemfile, I have cleared my apps heroku cache, it all still comes out to the same size.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101941/create-react-app-and-large-heruko-slug-size

Comment: Worth having a look in there to see if you aren't accidentally packaging your logs or stale webpack builds. That sounds like a lot of *something*.

Comment: thanks @TinNguyen for the comment, not really sure how that translates though. that is a frontend only application, and my frontend is gzipping down to 900kb, how does this translate to the ruby side?

Comment: Nevermind, I spoke too soon, after fiddling around with the solution linked, my slug size was reduce to 50mb, thanks tin!